# Why am I getting this error message in c++ (error: cannot convert 'std::__cxxll::string' )

Tags: c++

I am just starting out with C++ and I am stumped as to why I am getting this error.

The problem occurs when I call `display(students[i], marks[10][5]);`

Looks to me like I am passing the correct arguments and data types to the method.

I would appreciate if somebody could point out and explain the problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(int marks[5]);

int main() {
    string students[10] = {"Bob", "Jerry", "Mary", "Michael", "Brian", "Emma", "Sean", "Declan", "Ken", "Daniel"};

    int marks[10][5] = {{60, 87, 54, 98, 87},
                        {70, 69, 65, 98, 87},
                        {83, 64, 92, 98, 87},
                        {58, 45, 25, 98, 87},
                        {87, 19, 67, 98, 87},
                        {97, 74, 32, 98, 87},
                        {41, 77, 96, 98, 87},
                        {14, 78, 24, 98, 87},
                        {32, 98, 78, 98, 87},
                        {38, 97, 88, 98, 87}
                    };

    cout << "Displaying marks: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        display(students[i], marks[10][5]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(string student, int m[10][5]) {

    cout << "Student: " << << student << m[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        cout << m[j] << " ," << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of `display` doesn't match the definition; you're missing a parameter.

Comment: In function display you are trying to print a whole row of integers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually, it should be `display(students[i], marks[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *declaration* and *definition* of `display()` do not match.  You *declared* `display()` to take only a 1-dimensional array of `int`s, but you *defined* it to take a `string` and a 2-dimensional array of `int`s.

When you *call* `display()`, the compiler hasn't seen the *definition* yet, only the *declaration*, so you get an error trying to pass a `string` to an `int*` parameter.  Also, when passing a student's scores, you are passing in a single `int`, not an array of `int`s.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(string student, int marks[5]);

int main() {
    string students[10] = {"Bob", "Jerry", "Mary", "Michael", "Brian", "Emma", "Sean", "Declan", "Ken", "Daniel"};

    int marks[10][5] = {{60, 87, 54, 98, 87},
                        {70, 69, 65, 98, 87},
                        {83, 64, 92, 98, 87},
                        {58, 45, 25, 98, 87},
                        {87, 19, 67, 98, 87},
                        {97, 74, 32, 98, 87},
                        {41, 77, 96, 98, 87},
                        {14, 78, 24, 98, 87},
                        {32, 98, 78, 98, 87},
                        {38, 97, 88, 98, 87}
                    };

    cout << "Displaying marks: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        display(students[i], marks[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(string student, int marks[5])
{
    cout << "Student: " << student << " " << marks[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; ++j) {
        cout << ", " << marks[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/zuaf0P)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code:

- `display` is first declarated as `void display(int marks[5]);`, but
  then it is defined as `void display(string student, int m[10][5])`.
  It should be declarated `void display(string student, int m[5]);`.
- You're using `i` in `display`, but it shouldn't be there.
- When you use `marks[10][5]` as a parameter you're just passing an
  integer, not    the entire array.
- You have 2 `<<` in `display`. It should be just one.

It should work like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void display(string student, int m[5]);

int main() {
    string students[10] = {"Bob", "Jerry", "Mary", "Michael", "Brian", "Emma", "Sean", "Declan", "Ken", "Daniel"};

    int marks[10][5] = {{60, 87, 54, 98, 87},
                    {70, 69, 65, 98, 87},
                    {83, 64, 92, 98, 87},
                    {58, 45, 25, 98, 87},
                    {87, 19, 67, 98, 87},
                    {97, 74, 32, 98, 87},
                    {41, 77, 96, 98, 87},
                    {14, 78, 24, 98, 87},
                    {32, 98, 78, 98, 87},
                    {38, 97, 88, 98, 87}
                    };

    cout << "Displaying marks: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            display(students[i], marks[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


void display(string student, int m[5]) {

      cout<<"Student: " << student << endl;
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        cout << m[j] << ", ";
      }
      cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: ***When you use marks[10][5] as a parameter you're just passing an integer*** And that integer is past the end of the array.